# Is there any difference between "ability or not to be counted" and "ability to be counted or not"?

Tags: meaning, difference, interpretation

> many nouns that can be made plural are obviously able to be counted, and many that cannot be plural are obviously unable to be counted. The problem, however, is that there are also many nouns whose ability or not to be counted is unclear.

is there any semantic difference between saying "ability or not to be counted" and "ability to be counted or not"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these strike me as quite correct.  I would have written this as either *"ability (or lack thereof) to be counted"* or *"ability or inability to be counted."*

My reasoning here is that that the property that the text is talking about is not the noun's "ability not to be counted"—it's the noun's *lack of ability* (or *inability*) to be counted.

Comment: "lack of ability (or inability) to be counted" is much easier to understand. thanks now i got it but does it mean those phrases themselves are grammatical but a bit stiff and stilted?

Comment: @S.SHim10 I don't think either of my suggestions are particularly stilted. The original phrases are awkward (and arguably incorrect) because "ability or not" doesn't make sense—"not ability" isn't correct. Contrast this with "there or not," which *is* correct, because "not there" is correct.

Comment: what i meant was the original phrases. your suggestions are perfect that's helped me :) thanks for the extra tip!